# Autohotkey colour/image bot on vps?

Tags: autohotkey, vps

I'm runnings ahk scripts on a vps. It uses colour and images to perform tasks. The problem is I've to be connected through remote desktop 24/7 and keep the RD client in focus for it to work. As soon as I minimise/disconnect the remote desktop, the script stops working (pauses). 
I know there's no monitor attached in the vps. I need a workaround to this please.

Thank you.